# C# folders and sub folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to do this:

- Check if folder upload exists (if nor then create it) ~/ uploads
- Check if subfolder with username exists ~/uploads/folder with username

It as to check for each case individually because I could add a new user to the system and of course the folder uploads alredy exists, just need to create a sub folder with username

Answer (score 2):

In short:

1. Use [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to convert the virtual path (such as `~/uploads`) to a physical path.
2. Use [`Directory.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) to determine if the directory exists or not
3. If the directory does not exist, use [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) to create it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string userName = ""; // Substitute with logic for obtaining username
string folder = ResolveUrl( "~/Uploads" );

folder = System.IO.Path.Combine( folder, userName );

if ( !System.IO.Directory.Exists( folder ) )
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory( folder );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var path = string.Format(@"{0}Uploads\{1}",Request.PhysicalApplicationPath,
    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
using System;
using System.IO;     

   public void CreateDirectories(string uploadDirPath, string userName)
   {
     string userDirPath= uploadDirPath + "\\" + userName ;

     if (!Directory.Exists(uploadDirPath))
     {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDirPath);

       if (!Directory.Exists(userDirPath))
           Directory.CreateDirectory (userDirPath);
     }
   }
```

I leave it to you to wrap this up by calling the method in loops according to you specific logic and paramaterizing user names and folders